# Как написать регулярное выражение для sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Мне нужно регулярное выражение для sed которые будет пропускать строки которые начинаются с цифры и заканчиваются точкой.

```
1   The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890.
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890
4   The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890.
```

пропустить дложно только 4-ю строку

Comment: Пропустить — это выводить или не выводить?

Comment: А вообще — *man grep*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

где то так

```
sed -n '/^[0-9].*\.$/!p'  file.txt
```

`!p` инвертирует условие печати. Можно и условие вывернуть

```
sed -n '/^[^0-9].*[^\.]$/p'  ix.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Но как научится делать это самому?

Comment: ищите книгу "Фридл регулярные выражения".

Comment: оно пропустило "40-pin GPIO header detected"

Comment: логично - нет точки в конце

Comment: мне нужно что бы пропускало  "96    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890." и таких 25000, но не пропускало больше ничего.

Comment: я проверил. Первое выражение точно работает. Если это не так - выкладывайте файл строк, что хочется на выходе и какая строка вывелась (или не вывелась) ложно

Comment: 1    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890.
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890
4    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back 1234567890.
пропустить дложно только 4-ю строку

Comment: ага, только видно все как одна строка

Comment: я добавил "красиво" в описание

Comment: я проверил команду - она делает ровно то, что нужно (если я правильно понимаю, что "пропустить" - это не выводить)